# WPF - How do determine the index of the current item in a listbox from button handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have a listbox with a data template that contains a button.

When the button is clicked I want to get in the button
click handler the index of the listbox item that was current??

How do I do this please?

Malcolm

Answer (score 5):

More appropriate answer,

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

   while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListViewItem))
   {
     dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
   }

   if (dep == null)
    return;

   int index = lstBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dep); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListViewItem)) line use ListBoxItem instead of ListViewItem? With this fix, it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hope the bellow code will help you.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (Button)sender;
    var grid = (Grid)b.TemplatedParent
    var lstItem = (ListBoxItem)grid.TemplatedParent;
    int index = lstBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lstItem);
    // rest of your code here...
}
```

And the XAML for the above assumed to be a DataTemplate on a ListBox named `lstBox`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template">
  <Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Press"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The idea works but this code is somewhat brittle in that it assumes there will always be two hops from the `Button` up to the `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "SelectedIndex" property of the listbox? It might be set by clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Probably way to late but using "IndexOf" on the listbox "Items" will give you the index #
Regards

Answer (score 0):

`myListbox.Items.CurrentItem` seems be what you are looking for.

Comment: Google led me here - I was thinking this too, but for me the current item is always null. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I see my data in the listview, and I can change it, save it and reload it. What I can't do is get the currently selected item to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `ContentPresenter.Content` to get current item , instead of current index:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyModel}">                    
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />

                <Button Content="Active" Click="Button_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

and in code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var button = e.Source as Button;
            var contentPresenter = button.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter;
            var myModel = (MyModel)contentPresenter.Content;            
    }
```